# Консоль выдает ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src')

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

Как сделать так, чтобы у картинки изменился backgroundImage?

```html
<div id='photo' style="background-image: url('img/image.png');"> </div>

<script>
  var photo = document.getElementById('photo')
  photo.backgroundImage = url('img/image2.png')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [шаблонными строками](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), чтобы можно было использовать одиночные или двойные кавычки:

```js
var photo = document.getElementById('photo');
photo.style.backgroundImage = `url('img/image2.png')`;
```

```html
<div id='photo' style="background-image: url('img/image.png');"> </div>
```

Также такие строки позволяют легко вставлять переменные:

```js
var imagesUrl = ['img/image1.png','img/image2.png','img/image3.png'];
var photo = document.getElementById('photo');
photo.style.backgroundImage = `url('${imagesUrl[1]}')`;
```

```html
<div id='photo' style="background-image: url('img/image.png');"> </div>
```

Comment: почему не просто двойные кавычки?

Comment: @Grundy: на перспективу - вдруг человек решит использовать двойные внутри :)